# How to use a double value from an api in Flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, double

I feel kinda dumb asking this.  Because I was able to parse Maps and Lists from the api but I have no idea how to use something as simple as a double from the same api.

I simply want to make a

```
double yld;
```

from this api link,

https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/data-points/market/DGS10?token=Tsk_38ddda0b877a4510b42a37ae713cdc96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response body is a `String` so you'll have to parse it into a `double` using `double.parse()`

```dart
getYld() async {
  var url = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/data-points/market/DGS10? 
  token=Tsk_38ddda0b877a4510b42a37ae713cdc96';
  var res = await http.get(url);
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
     double yld = double.parse(res.body);  // parse the double here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I get an error "The await expression can only be used in an async function".  I am guess your put this inside a Future<double> >

Comment: You have to create an async function for this. i updated the code